# How To Style GridJS In VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, gridjs

I'm using Vue V.3 for my project and I'm using Grid.JS for my tables. Is there any way to style the table elements (i.e. th, tr, etc) of Grid? I already checked the [Grid.JS documentation for Vue](https://gridjs.io/docs/integrations/vue/) but there is no documentation for binding styles.

Comment: Can you use the className object?
https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/css-classname. Then you would use custom CSS in the <style> section of the template.

Comment: Grid.JS, for some reason, do not let Vue to bind the className object according to the documentation: https://gridjs.io/docs/integrations/vue

Comment: did you try that adding the className: object? on here it says it is optional https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs-vue#extended-options

Answer (score 1):

Use the className object and bind class-names

```
 <template>
  <grid
   :auto-width="autoWidth"
   :class-names="classNames"
   :width="width"
  ></grid>
 </template>
```

This will be in the script tag

```
<script>
import Grid from 'gridjs-vue'

export default {
  name: 'MyTable',
  components: {
    Grid
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cols: ['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3' ],
      rows: [
       ['John', 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
       ['Mark', 'mark@gmail.com',   '(01) 22 888 4444']
     ],
     classNames: {
       td: 'my-td-class',
       table: 'custom-table-class' 
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

then in the style section or a stylesheet add your CSS style

```
.my-td-class {
  background-color: red;
  }
```

**Or use a style Object**

It also seems you can add a style object
https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/css-style

Comment: Grid.JS, for some reason, do not let Vue to bind the className object and the style object according to the documentation: gridjs.io/docs/integrations/vue

Comment: I add the template code and bound the class-names, does that work? https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs-vue#extended-options

Comment: I have read the updated documentation link that you've sent me for the extended options. Unfortunately, it is still not working on my project. I'm using Vue Version 3 at the moment.

Comment: sorry, I did see you said V3 of vue. It works as outline in V2.  the vue package states "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },

Comment: Currently, what I am doing now is just inspecting the elements of the Grid.JS tables on the web browser to locate the class of each element that I want to style using CSS then edit their respective styles. Thank you very much for responding to my questions.

Comment: It seems doing as you are doing it the only solution at present.